# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level...why's that?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def play_game():

  # Show the initial game board
  display_board()

  # Loop until the game stops (winner or tie)
  while game_still_going:

    # Handle a turn
    handle_turn(current_player)

    # Check if the game is over
    check_if_game_over()

    # Flip to the other player
    flip_player()

  # Since the game is over, print the winner or tie
   if winner == "player1" or winner == "player2":
        print(winner + " won.")
```

Comment: Everything after the def must be indented by the same offset until the end of the function...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If statement should not be indented using spaces. Remove the spaces or tab which you used before the If statement.

It will remove the said error.